# How to get row and column of actual element in Octave/MatLab

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to get the row of the actual element (indX) in a matrix when I use this

```
matrix2 = matrix .* indX;
```

Suppose that matrix = ones(2,2)

I'm waiting matrix2 with these values [1 1; 2 2]
I can use "for" for this

```
[rows columns] = size(matrix)
    for (indX=0; indX<rows; indX++)
    matrix2(indX,:) = matrix(indX,:) .* indX;
endfor
```

Is it possible to get the indX without make use of "for" ?
If yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: Hi, are you asking whether you can get indX if you're given matrix2 and matrix?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. please re-phrase it.

Comment: Sorry, I was late when I wrote this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun`:

```
matrix2 = bsxfun(@times, (1:size(matrix,1))', matrix); %'
matrix =
 4     2
 3     3
 4     1
>> bsxfun(@times, (1:size(matrix,1))', matrix ), % '
ans =
 4     2
 6     6
12     3
```